# SWA-CLI Data API Builder issue with Node v18.16.0 and unzipper

Tags: swa-cli, data-api-builder

I am attempting to use SWA-CLI to run/debug a react web app in a PowerShell terminal in Visual Studio Code on my Windows PC.  My setup is:

```
OS: Windows 10 Pro (10.0.19044 Build 19044)
VS Code: 1.78.2
PowerShell: 5.1.19041.2673
SWA-CLI: 1.1.2
Node.js: 18.160.0
npm: 9.6.6
```

Problems first showed up when trying to initialize my project for database access:

```
PS C:\Local Development\react> swa db init --database-type mssql

Welcome to Azure Static Web Apps CLI (1.1.2)

[swa] Creating database connections configuration folder swa-db-connections
[swa] Creating staticwebapp.database.config.json configuration file
node:internal/errors:490
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

<ref *1> Error: spawnSync C:\Users\James98\.swa\dataApiBuilder\0.7.5\Microsoft.DataApiBuilder.exe UNKNOWN
    at Object.spawnSync (node:internal/child_process:1110:20)
    at spawnSync (node:child_process:871:24)
    at execFileSync (node:child_process:914:15)
    at execFileCommand (C:\Users\James98\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@azure\static-web-apps-cli\src\core\utils\command.ts:18:29)
    at init (C:\Users\James98\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@azure\static-web-apps-cli\src\cli\commands\db\init\init.ts:110:18)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Command.<anonymous> (C:\Users\James98\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@azure\static-web-apps-cli\src\cli\commands\db\init\register.ts:30:7)
    at Command.parseAsync (C:\Users\James98\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@azure\static-web-apps-cli\node_modules\commander\lib\command.js:935:5)
    at run (C:\Users\James98\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@azure\static-web-apps-cli\src\cli\index.ts:106:3) {  
  errno: -4094,
  code: 'UNKNOWN',
  syscall: 'spawnSync C:\\Users\\James98\\.swa\\dataApiBuilder\\0.7.5\\Microsoft.DataApiBuilder.exe',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\James98\\.swa\\dataApiBuilder\\0.7.5\\Microsoft.DataApiBuilder.exe',
  spawnargs: [
    'init',
    '--database-type',
    'mssql',
    '--config',
    'staticwebapp.database.config.json',
    '--rest.path',
    '/rest'
  ],
  error: [Circular *1],
  status: null,
  signal: null,
  output: null,
  pid: 0,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
```

I managed to work around the above error by creating a swa-db-connections folder and creating my own staticwebapp.database.config.json file (incidentally, when the project is uploaded to my StaticWebApp on Azure, the database connection works GREAT!).

The problem that I can't seem to get around, however, is simulating the project locally.  I start the local development server separately because swa doesn't seem to be able to detect when it is up-and-running, but when I try to get swa to manage the database connections, I receive a message saying that Microsoft.DataApiBuilder is not compatible with my Windows version?

```
PS C:\Local Development\react> swa start http://localhost:3000 --data-api-location ./swa-db-connections

Welcome to Azure Static Web Apps CLI (1.1.2)

***********************************************************************
* WARNING: This emulator may not match the cloud environment exactly. *
* Always deploy and test your app in Azure.                           *
***********************************************************************

[swa] ✔ Downloading https://github.com/Azure/data-api-builder/releases/download/v0.7.5/dab_win-x64-0.7.5.zip@0.7.5
[dataApi] This version of C:\Users\James98\.swa\dataApiBuilder\0.7.5\Microsoft.DataApiBuilder.exe is not compatible 
with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher.
[dataApi] cd "C:\Local Development\react\swa-db-connections" && "C:\Users\James98\.swa\dataApiBuilder\0.7.5\Microsoft.DataApiBuilder.exe" start -c staticwebapp.database.config.json --no-https-redirect exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[swa] node "C:\Users\James98\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@azure\static-web-apps-cli\dist\msha\server.js" exited with code 1
✖ SWA emulator stoped because SWA emulator exited with code 1.
```

I am not sure where to even start troubleshooting since I am running up-to-date versions of Windows, SWA-CLI, Node and npm...If anyone has any suggestions of what to try next, I would GREATLY appreciate them!

When I first encountered the error, I updated my toolset(s).  I don't know what version each tool was when I started. But I am getting the same behavior with the updated tools that are listed at the top.

Once doing that, I have tried uninstalling/reinstalling swa multiple times using:

```
npm uninstall  @azure/static-web-apps-cli
npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli
```

I have also tried deleting the folder at C:\Users\James98\.swa\dataApiBuilder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this is a issue of [`unzipper`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzipper) which is used for extracting the zip file of `DataApiBuilder`. It cannot work properly on Node v18.16.0. As a result, the extracted files are broken.

There are some options to resolve this issue.

Option 1. Upgrade swa-cli to v1.1.4 or later. This version doesn't use `unzipper`.
Option 2. Downgrade Node.js to v16.x or v18.15.0
Option 3. (Keep using Node 18.16.0) Extract `c:\users\{account}\.swa\dataApiBuilder\%VERSION_OF_DAB%\dab_win-x64-%VERSION_OF_DAB%.zip` manually into `c:\users\{account}\.swa\dataApiBuilder\%VERSION_OF_DAB%`

### Also

You may need to delete the folder or, at least, the contents of the folder at `%USERPROFILE%\.swa\dataApiBuilder\` so any invalid files can be replaced by valid files.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar error, and I was able to resolve it by downgrading my Node.js version from 18 to 16. After the downgrade, the `swa` command worked successfully.